# Preventing Opencascade to write to console

Tags: c++, logging, console, opencascade

When using the OpenCascade C++ libaries, certain functions will print out some status or response to the console/terminal.
For example [STEPCAFControl_Writer::perform()](https://old.opencascade.com/doc/occt-7.4.0/refman/html/class_s_t_e_p_c_a_f_control___writer.html#afa5f39a058322796db9324e3a6558f47) will print out something like:

```
*******************************************************************
******        Statistics on Transfer (Write)                 ******

*******************************************************************
******        Transfer Mode = 0  I.E.  As Is       ******
******        Transferring Shape, ShapeType = 0                      ******
** WorkSession : Sending all data
 Step File Name : <file-name>  Write  Done
```

to the console.
Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally OCCT does not print messages directly into console, instead it relies on `Message_Messenger` interface. Default implementation registers `Message_PrinterOStream` printer which puts all messages into console with colors assigned depending on a message gravity.

So, there are several options in your case:

- Suppress all OCCT messages by removing all printers within default messenger. This might be not a good idea as this will hide also error messages handful for failure analysis.

```cpp
  Message::DefaultMessenger()->RemovePrinters (STANDARD_TYPE(Message_PrinterOStream))
```

- Print only critical messages within default messenger by changing message gravity filter. Default filter is `Message_Info`, which means that all messages will be printed except `Message_Trace` designated for verbose or debug outputs.

```cpp
  Message_Gravity aGravity = Message_Alarm;
  for (Message_SequenceOfPrinters::Iterator aPrinterIter (Message::DefaultMessenger()->Printers());
       aPrinterIter.More(); aPrinterIter.Next())
  {
    aPrinterIter.Value()->SetTraceLevel (aGravity);
  }
```

- Remove `Message_PrinterOStream` and register your own printer implementing `Message_Printer` interface with desired behavior. Normally, GUI applications do not print messages to console and instead print them to dedicated GUI control basing on user preferences.

```cpp
  class MyPrinter : public Message_Printer
  {
  protected:
    virtual void send (const TCollection_AsciiString& theString, const Message_Gravity theGravity) const override
    {
      std::cerr << "[GRAV: " << theGravity << "] " << theString << "\n";
    }
  };
```

- When it comes to specific class `STEPCAFControl_Writer`, it should be noted that this class prints messages into `Transfer_TransferProcess::Messenger()`, which is set to a global `Message::DefaultMessenger()` messenger by default, but could be overridden by application in case if specific algorithm output should be suppressed / redirected. This would require diving into `STEPCAFControl` internal logic, as it doesn't look like an API easily accessible to application code... And it seems some messages will be print to `Message::DefaultMessenger()` anyway.

```cpp
  STEPCAFControl_Writer aWriter;
  Handle(Message_Messenger) aMessenger = new Message_Messenger();
  aMessenger->ChangePrinters().Clear();
  aMessenger->AddPrinter (new MyPrinter());
  aWriter.ChangeWriter().WS()->TransferWriter()->FinderProcess()->SetMessenger (aMessenger);
  ...
```

Below is a screenshot of Draw Harness showing messages with different gravity having different color (default behavior of `Message_PrinterOStream` since OCCT 7.5.0) - **intense red** for errors (`Message_Alarm`/`Message_Fail`), **intense yellow** for warnings (`Message_ConsoleColor_Yellow`), **intense green** for information (`Message_ConsoleColor_Green`), and **thin yellow** for verbose/debug messages (`Message_ConsoleColor_Yellow`).
[image: OCCT colored messages]

Comment: Your second suggestions "Print only critical message..." worked for me, thanks! However, it would be nice with some more details on your two last suggestions, still unclear for me how to override printing only from STEPCAFControl_Writer. And your image below, how does it relate to the answer/question?

Comment: Overriding messenger specifically for `STEPCAFControl_Writer` looks very hackish and doesn't look as well-defined API as anybody really use. I've added a code sample to the answer.